# g++ : was not declared in this scope despite included header

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, header, include

I am sure this is a trivial error. Nontheless I cannot find an error or a solution on Stackoverflow.
I have received above mentioned error for struct Transition, seemingly declared here :
Transition.h:

```
#ifndef ZOCK_TRANSITION_H
#define ZOCK_TRANSITION_H

#include <iostream>
#include "vec.h"
#include "dir.h"
#include "Board.h"

using std::ostream;
using std::endl;

struct Transition
{
    vec fromv;
    dir fromd;
    vec tov;
    dir tod;

    Transition();
    Transition(vec fromv, dir fromd, vec tov, dir tod);

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, cost Transition& t);
};

Transition swap(Transition& t) const;

#endif// ZOCK_TRANSITION_H
```

Error Message is :

```
g++ -std=c++14 -I./inc   -c src/Transition.cpp -o build/debug/Transition.o -g3
In file included from ./inc/Board.h:21:0,
                 from ./inc/Transition.h:19,
                 from src/Transition.cpp:12:
./inc/Map.h:29:9: error: ‘Transition’ was not declared in this scope
  vector<Transition> transitions;
```

So lets look into Map.h:

```
#ifndef ZOCK_MAP_H
#define ZOCK_MAP_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Transition.h"

using std::string;
using std::vector;

class Map
{
friend class Board;

private:
    int height, width;
    char ** fields;
    vector<Transition> transitions;

public:
    enum readfrom
    {
        str = 0,
        file ,

        NUM_READFROM //Leave last !
    };

    Map(string i, readfrom p);
};

#endif// ZOCK_MAP_H
```

It is unlikely that it is a compiler or linker error, since it seems every file was found correctly. Everything seems to be included correctly, so I am at a dead end.

What dows cause the error or what are common mistakes causing the error ?

Comment: You have a circular include. The error shows Map.h using `Transition` as part of Transition.h's includes.

Comment: seeing `src/Transition.cpp` and `inc/Board.h` would be helpful

Comment: It's true ! This should be an answer. I can search for solutions for circular includes now.